# Is it possible to "fill" a function argument, which defaults to null, with an object?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, optional-parameters, nullptr

Say I have this method:

```
bool match( /* some optional parameter */ );
```

that will do some string pattern matching and I wanted to allow it to be given an optional parameter that will only be filled with an instance of a known type (`Match`) when the method `match()` returns `true`, would such a thing be possible?

In PHP I would be allowed to do:

```
public function match( Match &$match = null ) {
  if( someMatchingRoutineMatched() ) {
    $match = new Match();
    return true;
  }

  return false; // $match will stay null
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
// $test is some instance of the class that implements match()
// I don't have to declare $m up front, since it will be filled by reference
if( $test->match( $m ) ) {
  // $m would be filled with an instance of Match
}
else {
  // $m would be null
}
```

Is something similar possible in c++?

I have kind of gotten it to work with the following

```
bool match( Match*& match ) {
  if( /* something matches */ ) {
    match = new Match;
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

... and then calling it like so:

```
Match* m = nullptr; // I wish I wouldn't have to declare this upfront as a nullptr
if( test.match( m ) ) {
  // a match occured, so m should no longer be a null pointer
  // but let's just make sure
  if( m != nullptr ) {
    // do something useful with m and afterwards delete it
    delete m;
  }
}
```

... however, this all feels a bit cumbersome. Furthermore I don't seem to be allowed to make the parameter optional like:

```
bool match( Match*& match = nullptr );
```

... since, I believe, references are not a allowed to be null, correct?

I hope you can see what I am trying to achieve and that you could give some insight in how I could go about achieving my goal, if it's at all possible to begin with, that is.

Comment: Have two overloads, one taking nothing, the other as you have but with no default.

Comment: @DanMašek Okay, that would solve the optional bit, but would there still be a way to keep `match` as `null` when `match()` returned `false`? Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is guarantee that `match` will *only* be filled with an instance of `Match` when there has *indeed* been found a match, and otherwise have it be `null`. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, see the answers below.

Comment: In `C++` and also in `PHP` you can return `NULL` instead of `false` and the new object instead of `true`. If the value returned by the method is not `NULL` then the calling code can store it into the variable you pass to `match()`. This way it is clear for the reader when the value of `$m` changes (right now one have to read the code of function match() to learn this fact.)

Answer (score 4):

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Match*&' from an rvalue of type 'Match*'

`Match*& match = nullptr` is not allowed because references-to-non-const cannot bind to temporaries and passing `nullptr` here creates a temporary `Match*`.

---

You could return the pointer instead of passing a reference-to-non-const:

```
Match* match() {
  if( /* something matches */ ) {
    return new Match;
  }

  return nullptr;
}
```

Now a `nullptr` return value means no matches, and non-`nullptr` means that a match was found:

```
if( Match* m = test.match() ) { // nullptr means false, non-nullptr means true
  if( m != nullptr ) { // always true here
    // do something useful with m and afterwards delete it
    delete m;
  }
}
```

---

Or you could use overloading as @DanMašek mentioned:

```
bool match() {
  Match* m = nullptr;
  bool result = match(m);
  delete m; // deleting a nullptr is a no-op
  return result;
}
```

---

Last but definitely not least, mandatory use-`unique_ptr`-over-raw-owning-pointer, so you don't have to worry about `delete`, and it's clear without reading the documentation of `match` whether the returned pointer is owning or non-owning:

```
unique_ptr<Match> match() {
  if( /* something matches */ ) {
    return make_unique<Match>( /* constructor arguments */ );
  }

  return nullptr;
}

if( auto m = test.match() ) { // m deduced to be of type unique_ptr<Match>
  if( m != nullptr ) { // always true here
    // do something useful with m and afterwards delete it
    // no need to delete explicitly
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, returning a nullptr is certainly an option I will consider, however, I kind of like the explicit `bool`, with the optional argument. And as I've commented elsewhere, I'm kind of surprised to read that this style I had in mind is not a ubiquitous as I thought it was in either C or C++. I thought PHP borrowed that style from C (since many PHP functions resemble the C API). Anyway, thank you as well, for your very valuable input.

Comment: I think it's more ubiquitous in C than C++ as pointed out in Christian Hackl's answer. In modern C++ (C++11 and later) out-params are rarely needed. Using the return value for all necessary output also makes the interface simpler.

Comment: Right on! It seems I've got a lot of material to contemplate in order to figure out what best suits my intentions and what makes the most sense in the context of C++. You've all been very helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: @DecentDabbler If you don't like handling pointer directly, you can always wrap the handling in a class which overloads `operator bool` and sweetens the other operations you need. Pretty much what Cristian Hackl suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers to pointers, references to pointers or optional "out" arguments are all more C-style coding and/or simply not very idiomatic in C++.

Nor is using dynamic allocation (`new Match`) when it's not clearly needed.

A more C++-like solution to your problem would be [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html), an implementation of a C++ idiom sometimes called "Fallible". The idea is to return an object with two member variables, one signalling success, the other one being the "real" return value in case the first one is true.

You can also implement a basic version yourself, and while we're at it, replace the pointer with a normal instance, because `Match` does not sound like a class whose instances need to be allocated dynamically<sup>[*]</sup>.

```
struct Result
{
    bool success;
    Match match;
};
```

A more elaborate implementation would turn this into a class with private member variables and public member functions making sure that accessing `match` fails if `success` is false:

```
class Result
{
public:
    bool success() const { return m_success; }
    Match match() const {
        assert(m_success);
        return m_match;
    }

    Result() : m_success(false), m_match() {}
    Result(Match const& match) : m_success(true), m_match(match) {}

private:
    bool m_success;
    Match m_match;
};
```

The `match()` function itself would then look like this:

```
Result match()
{
    if (someMatchingRoutineMatched()) {
        return Result(Match(some_match_arguments));
    }

    return Result();
}
```

The caller would then use it like this:

```
auto const result = match();
if (result.success())
{
    // use result.match()
}
```

If you add a `bool` conversion operator to your class, i.e.:

```
    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return m_success;
    }
```

then you can also write the `if` as follows to make it look more like your original PHP code, although I don't think it's more readable like this, and I would recommend against it:

```
if (auto const result = match()) {
    // use result.match()
} else {
    // access to result.match() neither allowed nor needed
}
```

---

<sup>[*] If you do need dynamic allocation, for example because `Match` is part of polymorphic class hierarchy, then consider `std::unique_ptr`.</sup>

Comment: Since I'm new to c++ I'll have to look into what dynamic allocation exactly entails, but I'll figure that one out. And although your solution is a bit more involved than what I had in mind, it's an interesting approach, that I have used in PHP, in a similar fashion, on occasion as well. So thank you as well for a valuable alternative approach.

Comment: @DecentDabbler: In a nutshell, dynamic allocation happens with `new`, or smart pointers on a higher level, when the lifetime of an object in memory is no longer bound to the scope of a variable in the source code, which means that its destructor is not run when a block ends. This usually makes code more complicated, but of course it's rare to see programs which can get away with no any dynamic allocation at all. Bare `new`s are the worst offender. See http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/ (section "Smart pointers: No delete")

Answer (score 1):

I like very much the c/c++ style of returning a `nullptr` if it's false proposed by @zenith.

But for the records, here another alternative:

```
bool match( Match*& match ) {
  bool some_condition=true; 
  if( some_condition ) {
    match = new Match;
    return true;
  }
  match = nullptr;   // so that you don't need to set it upfront
  return false;
}

bool match() {       // here if you don't have any pointer to provide
    Match *forget_it; 
    return match(forget_it);
}
```

However, there's a weakness, because if you always create a new Match in the free store, you'd leak memory. So the anonymous version has to be updated:

```
bool match() {
    Match *forget_it; 
    bool rc=match(forget_it);
    delete forget_it;  // avoid leaking memory
    return rc;
}
```

Unfortunately, it's still possible that the caller from the plain Match() foregets to free memory.  So I'd suggest using a `unique_ptr<Match>` or a `shared_ptr<Match>` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Right! The "forgetting to free memory" was what worried me a bit as well, but since I'm new to c++ I'll have to look into what `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` do exactly. Thank you for your very valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way to handle this would probably be to return a pointer to the created object if the `match` succeeded, or `nullptr` otherwise, as zenith suggested. But if you want something more analogous to what you do in PHP, I'd suggest the following:

```
#include <memory>

bool match(std::unique_ptr<Match>& ptr)
{
    bool some_condition = true;
    if(some_condition) {
        ptr = std::make_unique<Match>();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

bool match()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Match> ptr;
    return match(ptr);
}

int main()
{
   match(); // if Match is created, it's automatically discarded
   std::unique_ptr<Match> ptr;
   if(match(ptr))
   {
       // do stuff with ptr
       // ptr will be deleted once it goes out of scope
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I was under the assumption that this style was rather ubiquitous in C/C++, since I thought PHP actually borrowed this style from C, since PHP's functions largely derive from the C API. Perhaps I'm just imagining things. I'm kind of surprised to read that this style is not that common in C/C++. Anyway, your answer seems to resemble most closely what my original intent was. I'll have to study it (all the answers so far, for that matter) some more. But thank you so far, as well, for your very valuable input!

Comment: @DecentDabbler `C != C++`, especially in terms of code style :)

Comment: @DecentDabbler: There is really no style "rather ubiquitous in C/C++", because those are two different languages with different philosophies and ideas about what's good and bad coding style.